# Gideros image dynamic load and delete from memory

Tags: android, ios, lua, gideros

I would like to make an mobile application, what contains a lot of picture
My question how can I dynamically open the picture and delete from memory?

I tested this:

```
a = Texture.new("a.jpg")
print(Application:getTextureMemoryUsage()) -- write x
a = nil
print(Application:getTextureMemoryUsage()) -- write x again
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that garbage is not collected right away and that is why memory is not freed right away.
You could try calling `collectgarbage()` couple of times to force it as:

```
print(math.floor(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage()
collectgarbage()
collectgarbage()
print(math.floor(collectgarbage("count")))
```